# Regardless of request how return same Controller/Action

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm building an application with AngularJs and it's using Html5 routing.  The issue is when you refresh the page the route isn't valid.  Now I could go through and add an entry for every route and return my main page (which is what I've done) but I was wondering if there is a singular way to always return the same page, lets say controller="Home", Action="Index", no matter what url request comes in.

Comment: Did you try reach this with routing defaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");



        // We have an angular application. All other pages routing is done there
        // This route must be the last one!
        routes.MapRoute(
             "Default",
             "{*url}",
             new { controller = "AngularApp", action = "Layout" }
         );
    }
}
```

In my example, as you can see all the requests are directed to **AngularAppController**, **Layout** Action